# expint c++ method om Macos M1

Tags: c++, macos, clang, apple-m1, cmath

i tried run method **expint** from cmath and got error, i used c++17, c++17 should support this method but it doesn't see it. C++ version Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2). which version should I use so that the expint method is available?

```
//#define __STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ 1
//#define __STDCPP_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ 201003L

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    
    std::expint(10.4);
    return 0;
}
```

[expint docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/special_functions/expint) [one more expint docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions/expint)

error

[image: error]

c++ configs
[image: c++ configs]

Answer (score -1):

It may be a compatibility issue with the updated MacOS version or even the M1 (if you have it) chipset. With just the info on the application, it is still undeterminable what the root cause may be.

Comment: What could chipset have to do with build error due to standard library missing a function?

Comment: This is not the answer. The issue is a _compile-time_ issue. Most likely the LLVM version shipped with Xcode just doesn't contain the functions yet.